# Why Invalidate() should be called outside the control then it can work?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, datasource, invalidation

I am using C# + winforms to develop software.
I have a UserControl which contains several DataGridView

```
datagridview1.datasource = from p in dc.doctor select p;
```

I use linq to sql to populate the dataGridView with dataSource, because I need to refresh the datasource to update the records, so I create a new dataContext and assign the datasource again.

```
datagridview1.datasource = from p in dc.doctor select p;
```

At first I found, although I reset the datasource, the datagridview still can not get refreshed, someone tell me that I should call the invalidate function on datagridview, I tried. To a certain extent, it works.
But If I called the Invalidate inside the UserControl's class, it won't work.
If I create a public function on the UserControl's class, then call it with userControl.refreshRecord(),  Then it works.

Can someone point me what am I missed ? When someone call invalidate, when will it really work?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's not being called within the containing control that's the problem, it's being called during processing of some particular message that doesn't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalidate work when the control finish all other things like data loading ...

Answer (score -1):

Call [`dgv.Invalidate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) method for datagridview.

Comment: Did you finish to read my question ? I called the invalidate function, but if I call it inside the control, it won't work. I have to call it outside the usercontrol, then it works.

Comment: wonderful correct answer is that it works and you are wrong. wow what a sick guy